ajax POST in aspnet controller always value null
in my asp net core 8 project i have a ajax post but
parameter value return always null
I have already write builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(); in my Program.cs file
this is my controller code
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    [Route("Test")]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("index")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [Route("callPost")]
        public IActionResult CallPost(ParamClass model)
        {


            return View();
        }
    }

    public class ParamClass()
    {
        public string P1 { get; set; }
        public string P2 { get; set; }
    }
} 

this is my ajax post call
 $(document).ready(function () {


            var model = {
                p1: "a",
                p2: 'b'
            };

            $.post({
                url: "/test/callPost",
                data: JSON.stringify({ model }),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (data) { 
            });

        });
 

enter image description here

i have resolved in this method   public IActionResult CallPost([FromBody] JObject model)
but why if i change JObject with ParamClass i have always null value?

Looks like a jQuery post call but using Ajax long format... try: $.post('/test/callPost', model, function(data) { .... deal with successful response here... }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {... deal with error here... });

the mixture of single and double quotes is a little odd too... maybe try with:   var model = {
p1: "a",
p2: "b"
};

You need use JSON.stringify(model).

The Answer
You don't really need JSON.stringify here - just use your JavaScript model:
$.post({
    url: "/test/callPost",
    data: model,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) { 
});

$.post will handle serializing the object for you. If you really want to use JSON.stringify, then omit the braces:
$.post({
    url: "/test/callPost",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (data) { 
});

The Why
When you call this line of code:
JSON.stringify({ model })

you're first creating a new object with your model as a property.
{
    "model": {
        p1: "a",
        p2: 'b'
    }
}

Then, that new model is serialized to:
"{\&quot;model\&quot;:{\&quot;p1\&quot;:\&quot;a\&quot;,\&quot;p2\&quot;:\&quot;b\&quot;}}"

That won't match the model of your CallPost() action. Passing the model directly to JSON.stringify,
JSON.stringify(model)

will return
"{\&quot;p1\&quot;:\&quot;a\&quot;,\&quot;p2\&quot;:\&quot;b\&quot;}"

which will correctly bind to your C# model.
For reference, this jsFiddle demonstrates the different results based on how you call JSON.stringify: https://jsfiddle.net/hv63gsc9/

i remove JSON.stringify from ajax request but model in public IActionResult CallPost(ParamClass model) is always null

@AlexB Not sure what to tell you. Perhaps try simplifying your AJAX call. You really only need $.post("/test/callPost", model).done(function(response, status, jqxhr){}); - that's mostly how I use $.post (I also add a handler for the failed response)
